# Challenging django queryset construction

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django app where users log in, set various topics, and then leave comments under the said topics. The following models reflect this rudimentary set up:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    topic_text = models.TextField()
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    which_topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

For each user, I am trying to get **all topics** where any one of the **most recent 5 comments** were written by the user. In other words, if a user has not commented among a topic's most recent 5 comments, the topic will be excluded from the queryset.

So how do I go about forming this queryset? Btw I was going to show you what I've tried, but it's woefully inadequate and obviously wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: I think it doesn't make sense to try to select the topics on which this user has commented and only if the comment is within the top 5, although it would probably be possible using nested queries. Instead I'd rather select the topics this user has commented on and then filter them by the position of the comment in the code (and cache that because it's heavy).

Comment: I agree. It's the *and then filter them by the position of the comment* part that I'm finding almost impossible to wrap my head around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but a subquery should work. Something like this:

```
Topic.objects.filter(
    comment__submitted_by__in=Comment.objects.values(
        'submitted_by'
    ).order_by(
        '-submitted_on'
    ).limit(5),

    submitted_by=user
)
```

(Add `.prefetch_related('comment_set')` if you plan to access the comments.)

Comment: None of our suggestions work when I look closer at the requirements I'm afraid. I'll edit and we will think some more.

Comment: your edit now considers all the comments... the point is that the subquery, as it is, has no way of knowing how to select only the comments related to the current topic

Comment: Exactly :-( And it's probably better to do a second filtering in Python than doing something more complicated.